# Django Rest Framework Incorrect Model View response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some issue with drf, can someone point out what am i doing wrong ?

This is my views function, I have also  implemented  easy_thumbnails so that i can crop the image if such a request is made.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Image
from .serializers import ImageSerializer
from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer

class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        height = request.GET.get('height', None)
        width = request.GET.get('width', None)
        print("height = {}".format(height))
        print("width = {}".format(width))
        print("id = {}".format(pk))
        img = Image.objects.get(pk = pk)
        if height and width:
            options = {'size': (height, width), 'crop': True}
            thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(img.image).get_thumbnail(options).url
        else:
            thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(img.image).url
        return Response(thumb_url)
```

right now if  goto `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/` it returns me a list of images

and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/1/?height=320&width=420` returns a response like

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

"/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg.320x420_q85_crop.jpg"
```

I want a response like this with field names.

```
{
    "title": "Item 1",
    "description": "Description 1",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg"
}
```

How can i fix this issue ? I am new to drf and django

this is my serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Image

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    height = request.query_params.get('height', None)
    width = request.query_params.get('width', None)
    img = self.get_object()
    if height and width:
        options = {'size': (height, width), 'crop': True}
        thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(img.image).get_thumbnail(options).url
    else:
        thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(img.image).url
    serializer = self.get_serializer(img)
    # insert thumb_url into data if you need it
    response_dict = {}
    response_dict.update(serializer.data)
    response_dict['image'] = thumb_url
    return Response(response_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, It works however there is a problem,
when i send params to crop the image , i still get the image url and not the thumb_url : 
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/1/?height=320&width=420

Comment: I get this:
{
    "title": "Item 1",
    "description": "Description 1",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg"
}

Comment: previously i would get a cropped image url , if i passed in height and width to the get request.
eg :  127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/1/?height=320&width=420 
I would get this

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

"/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg.320x420_q85_crop.jpg"

Comment: @ZeeS I have edited the answer to correct the code. I have included a new field `thumb_url`. Do you want to replace `image` field with the new url?

Comment: Yes, If the client requests the cropped image, i want to send the cropped url.

Comment: @ZeeS updated the answer to replace image value with thumb_url

Comment: it works like a charm but another small issue popped up.

The url does not contain the hostname: 

 "image": "/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg",

Comment: @ZeeS use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri. I haven't used easy_thumbnails, check out it's docs to see if it can give you a complete url.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, truly appreciate it and I did learn a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this,

```
return Response({"title": img.title, "description": img.description,
                 "image": img.image, "thumbnail": thumb_url})
```

Comment: This did not work,my serializer_class is already defined, i need to figure out a way to use that.

UnicodeDecodeError at /api/images/1/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: but you need thumbnail image url too, isn't it?